# when including a file using php function not work?

Tags: php

**MY PHP FUNCTION IS**

```
function functionName()
{
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/path/file.php");
}
```

**Content of File.php is**

```
$foo = 'bar';
```

**Calling function (content of file test.php)**

functionName();

**When call function and variable not work**

```
echo $foo;  <- not works
```

But when adding code below its works (content of file test.php)

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/path/file.php");
echo $foo; <- its works
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function functionName()
{
global $foo;
global $bar;

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/path/file.php");
}
functionName();
echo $foo;
echo $bar;
```

Answer (score 3):

All variables handled in a function are limited only to that function. You can create numberless variables in a function but these variables won't be available to you outside the function except the return variable.

```
function thisIsMyFunction () {
  $var1 = "foo";
  $var2 = "bar";
  return $var1;
}

echo thisisMyFunction();
```

Will give you "foo" which you can put in a variable or echo out. If you're looking for a way to load multiple variables for example a config file you could do the following:

```
config.php
$config["var1"] = "foo";
$config["var2"] = "bar";

index.php
include "config.php";

function myFunction(){
  global $config;
  echo $config["var1"] . " " . $config["var2"];
}

myFunction();

will result in

foo bar
```

So in short, something done in the function stays in the function unless some output of that function isn't defined. This is why including with a function will not work.

Comment: What about this 
function thisIsMyFunction () {
  $var2 = "bar";
  $config["var2"] = "bar";
}

thisIsMyFunction();
echo $var2;????

Comment: @JohnSmiith Setting another value for a global var works from a function, but only along the lines of the second example. So the global var must exist and be included into the function to be manipulated in the function.

Answer (score 1):

That's because if you don't include the other file, where `$foo` is defined, it can't just make up values for it.

**But when adding `include("/path/file.php");` its works.**

*Of course it does. Now, an important thing: Are you including based off of the domain name?*

Example: http://www.site.com/path/to/file.php would include from http://www.site.com/path/file.php in the current setup. Here's how includes work:

1. `/file.php` >> file is in the domain's root. HAS TO BE in domain's
   root.
2. `./file.php` >> file is in the same directory.
3. `../file.php` >> file is in the parent directory.
4. `../../file.php` >> file is in the grandparent directory.

*(and so forth).*

What `include()` and `require()` and their related functions do, is include another file as if it were part of the file that's including them. Here are the differences:

**Include and require are identical, except upon failure:**

- require will produce a fatal error (E_COMPILE_ERROR) and the script will kill itself
- include will only produce a warning (E_WARNING) and the script will
  finish the rest of the commands

Comment: i upgrade my question please check

Comment: Hmm... You're using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` why? This returns the physical path to the file as it exists to the local operating system. If that's indeed your goal, make SURE that PHP has permissions to find this information. Don't forget the underscores either.